# iOS - Facebook API - Permission to get the username

Tags: ios, facebook, api

This is my code:

```
  NSArray *permissions = @[@"read_friendlists", @"email",@"user_about_me",@"user_status"];

    // OPEN Session!
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState status,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                                      if (error) {

                                          //NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                                          // show error to user.

                                      } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {

                                          // no error, so we proceed with requesting user details of current facebook session.
                                          //NSLog(@"we are here");
                                          //NSLog(@"----%@",[session accessTokenData].accessToken);

                                          NSString *tok = [session accessTokenData].accessToken;
                                          NSLog(@"tok 2");



                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {

                                                  NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  NSLog(@"all dat %@",user);
                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                                         user.location[@"name"]]);

                                              }
                                          }];



                                          // [self promptUserWithAccountName];   // a custom method - see below:
                                      }




                                  }];
}
```

which it seems to work except for the "username" which is the most important part of the code! Am I missing something? I have tried a lot of permissions but nothing is giving the username. I am always getting nil. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of the SDK and API are you using? username doesn't exist in API version 2.0, which all new apps will be using by default, as will apps using the current SDK version, unless they specifically request version 1.0 on an API call

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of the iOS SDK, you'll be hitting v2.0 of the Graph API. `username` has been deprecated in v2.0 of the Graph API.